# Find Identical columns in a matrix in C

Tags: c

In this exercise I filled a matrix and I search for identical pairs of columns. I use a boolean function to check if two tables are identical and I put another function which displays the indices of identical columns in the matrix, but the output shows nothing, can you help me...

```
bool Equal_Column(int n, int T1[n], int T2[n]) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {          
        if (T1[i] == T2[i]) {    
            k++;                
        }  
    }          

    if (k == n) {
        return true; 
    } else {           
        return false;
    }           
} 
         
int Know_Equal_Column(int n, int m, int T1[n][m]) {          
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {      
        for (int j = i + 1; j < m; j++) {  
            if (Equal_Column(n, T1[i], T1[j])) {             
                printf("\nThe two columns %d and %d are identical !\n", i, j);
            }             
        }  
    }      
}
  
int main() {          
    int n, m;
    do {      
        printf("Give n the number of lines in this matrix : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 1);

    do {      
        printf("Give n the number of columns in this matrix : ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
    } while (m < 1);
    int T1[n][m];
    printf("\nThe filling of this matrix : \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {      
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {  
            scanf("%d", &T1[i][j]);
        }  
    }      
    (n, m, T1);
}
```

Comment: `(n,m,T1);` Something seems to be lost, here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you do not call the function at the end: `Know_Equal_Column(n, m, T1)`.
- you cannot pass *column* pointers to `Equal_Column` as coded, your code passes row pointers and potentially iterates beyond the last row if `m` is greater than `n`.
- you should combine `Equal_Column` into the `Know_Equal_Column` function or change the prototype to take both column numbers, the number of rows and the matrix pointer.
- changing the variable names to `cols` and `rows` may improve readability as `n` and `m` may cause confusion.

Here is a modified version:

```
bool Equal_Column(int rows, int cols, int i, int j, int T1[rows][cols]) {
    for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
        if (T1[k][i] != T2[k][j]) {    
            return false;
        }  
    }          
    return true;
} 
         
void Know_Equal_Column(int rows, int cols, int T1[rows][cols]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {      
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cols; j++) {  
            if (Equal_Column(rows, cols, i, j, T1)) {             
                printf("\nThe two columns %d and %d are identical!\n", i, j);
            }             
        }  
    }      
}
  
int main() {          
    int rows, cols;
    do {      
        printf("Give n the number of lines in this matrix : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1)
            return 1;
    } while (rows < 1);

    do {      
        printf("Give n the number of columns in this matrix : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &cols) != 1)
            return 1;
    } while (cols < 1);

    /* define the 2D matrix with variable dimensions as local VLA.
       note that this feature is optional as of the latest version of the C Standard.
       also note that large values of cols or rows may cause undefined behavior
    */
    int T1[rows][cols];

    printf("\nThe filling of this matrix : \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {      
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {  
            if (scanf("%d", &T1[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }  
    }      
    Know_Equal_Column(rows, cols, T1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call to Know_Equal_Column() is missing in the main function.

Comment: Yes,Excuse me,I forget it